# Rank and unrank for Heap's Algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, enumeration

I am looking for an unranking (and ranking) algorithm for permtuations that is consistent with the order that [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) generates permutations.

I have been researching a bit on ranking and unranking of permutation algorithms.

A ranking function for the permutations on n symbols assigns a unique integer in the range [1, n!] to each of the n! permutations. The corresponding unranking function is the inverse: given an integer between 1 and n!, the value of the function is the permutation having this rank.

Example: The permutation [ABCD] has rank 1 as it is the first permutation. Rank 2 is [BACD].
When trying to generate the permutations in parallel, the work needs to be divided. There are 4! = 24 permutations on the four symbols ABCD.  Parallelizing across two processors would mean 12 permutations for each thread, but requires to unrank position 13, to get the start permutation for the 2nd thread [ACDB].

There are plenty unrank algorithms for lexicographic permutations, few on Johnson-Trotter, there is Ruskey and Myrvold (seems another order), but I could not find a single paper or implementation that is suitable for use with a parallel implementation of Heap's Algorithm.

This surprises me a bit, as it is repeatedly stated that Heap's algorithm is the fastest algorithm for generating all permutations, but parallelization would require such functionality (unrank).

Any help on the mathematical logic to quickly calculate the permutation on any given rank would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the revisions!  I made some additional edits based on my understanding of your question.  It would be great if you could check whether my changes are accurate and correct any errors I have introduced.

Comment: Thanks, very accurate.